# Progress Bar - Loop Through Array and Display Divs

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, progress-bar

Getting really stuck on this one... I'm trying to build a donation progress bar...  In ReactJS - but I'm a beginner, so I want to get the code right first in Vanilla js...

What I'm trying to do, is loop through an array of numbers, (aka, donations already submitted via a form).  EG:

[2, 5, 25] etc.

Everytime, a donation is submitted, it get's added to this array.

Want I want, is for my donation bar to increase/fill in colour, based on the donations already made in the array.

The bar would be full at 100%. Or £100.

Here's the snippet of JS I already have:

```
  // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
const numbers = donated.map(Number);
  function add(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
// SUM VALUE OF NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY
const sum = numbers.reduce(add, 0);
console.log('numbers', numbers);

//THE VALUE OF NUMBERS IN ARRAY, TURNED INTO A PERCENTAGE
const total = 100;
const percentage = (sum / total) * 100;
console.log('percentage', percentage);

// LOOP THROUGH EVERY NUMBER IN THE ARRAY, AND ADD A DIV WITH A MATCHING WIDTH  
for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
  if (i < 100) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.background = 'red';
    div.style.width = numbers + 'px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.style.float = 'left';
    document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

The loop works, slightly.  The first div in the array gets added.  But as I add more donations, no more divs are added to the progress bar.

Eventually, I want to stop at 100...

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! I needed to set numbers[i] in my style width:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
if (i < 100) {
  div +1;
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.background = 'red';
  **div.style.width = numbers[i] + 'px';**
  div.style.height = '50px';
  div.style.float = 'left';
  document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(div);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you styled your divs float left. That mean each div will appears over the previous on left. In chrome, right click on the div and left click on inspect. You will see that you have many divs generated in your Dom.

Comment: No that's not it.  The float left, allows my divs to sit next to each other, so the progress bar can fill with colour, on each click/donation.